# AwesomeWM: Error when initialising a theme

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

I've currently started using the AwesomeWM and started configuring it. I struggle at theming: whenever I try to change the theme, I get this error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAbuW.png

It tells me that the error is on the line 553/554, but if I don't adjust any themes, they work without any errors.

Code for theming:

```
local theme_path = string.format("%s/.config/awesome/themes/%s/theme.lua", os.getenv("HOME"), "powerarrow")
beautiful.init(theme_path)
```

Lines the error says are wrong (553/554):

```
client.connect_signal("focus", function(c) c.border_color = beautiful.border_focus end)
client.connect_signal("unfocus", function(c) c.border_color = beautiful.border_normal end)
```

So, what's the problem?

Comment: `border_focus` and `border_normal` seem to be variables supposed to be set in your theme file. Can you find any such variables there?

Comment: Yes.
They're set as theme.border_normal = "#3F3F3F" and theme.border_focus                            = "#6F6F6F"